# Python byte array equivalent in Rust

Tags: python, rust, byte, endianness

I'm looking to get this in rust:

```
print(len(x).to_bytes(2, byteorder="little"))
b'\n\x00
```

What is the equivalent to this in rust? How do I get this byte string? I need to send this string in a request, so I need this raw string format. I experimented with {:x}, but this doesn't seem to be the equivalent

Comment: What data are you trying to serialize to bytes?

Comment: If it is an integer of some sort, you can use `42.to_le_bytes()`

Comment: If you want a string representation of an integer in the form of raw bytes, you can use `42.to_string().into_bytes()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a byte array representing a 16-bit integer in little-endian byte order by using [`u16::to_le_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html#method.to_le_bytes):

```rust
fn main() {
    let len: u16 = 110;
    let len_bytes: [u8; 2] = len.to_le_bytes();
    println!("{len_bytes:?}");
}
```

```
[110, 0]
```